# Constructing a service/daemon using runit

Tags: linux, ubuntu, daemon, sysvinit

I need to make a time syncing service for some SysV-based Linux system, but I want to use Ubuntu as a development environment. For this and some other reasons I've decided to use [runit](http://smarden.org/runit/) as a universal and convenient tool. But here are some troubles I have:

1. How do I make it run in my SysV-based system? It seems it has a module (`runsvdir`) that needs to be started. I've compiled from sources and done `make install` [as instructed](http://smarden.org/runit/install.html), but see no changes in `/etc/init.d/`. Do I have to add `runsvdir` to `/etc/init.d` manually?
2. How do I make my console app react to control signals? Does it need some kind of special code to do it, or it is enough to do just `while(1){waitdata();processdata();}`? I've searched for samples but find only bash scripts with sleep command.

Comment: Tried to add "runit" tag, but it says I couldn't because it is a new one and I need a reputation to do it